# Postgres query syntax error . I am querying in navicat

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I try to add quotes. But it did not work:

I'm using Postgres.

Here is my query in navicat which results in syntax errors:

```
WITH t1 AS 
(
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        "olympics_history" 
)
```

Comment: you are missing a final query _after_ the `WITH` part. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not work . can you write please . where

Comment: `WITH` is a place where you define subqueries that you will use in final query.  Check link provided by @a_horse_with_no_name, and you see that after closing bracket should be a query... or if you want only list all records from "olympics_history" than you don't need WITH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works like this:

```
WITH t1 AS 
(
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        "olympics_history" 
)
SELECT games 
FROM t1 
WHERE t1.season = 'Summer'
```

Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name